# 'dllimport' attribute ignored and undefined reference errors while building wxWidgets with clang

Tags: c++, clang, wxwidgets

I very need to build **wxWidgets** with **clang** on **Windows** for my current project, and I've build **wxWidgets 3.0.3** and **3.1.0** on windows with native **clang llvm 5.0.0**, using **mingw-w64 7.2.0, 64 bit, seh, posix threads** standard library and tools (**x86_64-w64-windows-gnu** target). Samples are working. But I'm unable to link dll's except the main one. So I can't build opengl dll in monolithic shared build and all dlls with MONOLITHIC=0. There are some errors with headers/precompiled headers. While compiling I have many `redeclared inline; 'dllimport' attribute ignored` warnings like:

```
In file included from ../../src/xrc/xmlreshandler.cpp:18:
In file included from ..\..\include\wx/xrc/xmlreshandler.h:22:
In file included from ..\..\include\wx/window.h:18:
..\..\include\wx/event.h:3750:35: warning: 'wxObjectEventFunctor::operator()' redeclared inline; 'dllimport' attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
inline void wxObjectEventFunctor::operator()(wxEvtHandler *handler, wxEvent& even
```

t)

and then linker `undefined reference` errors like:

```
 clang_mswuddll-forest\coredll_appcmn.o:(.rdata[_ZTV12wxAppConsole]+0x1e0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to wxAppConsoleBase::FilterEvent(wxEvent&)'
```

In case of monolithic build I had warnings in compilation stage only in file `src/common/glcmn.cpp`, so I had compiled a library with command like:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=1 SHARED=1 BUILD=debug USE_OPENGL=0 CFLAGS=" -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unused-command-line-argument " CXXFLAGS=" -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fexceptions -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fnon-call-exceptions -std=gnu++11 -pthread " LDFLAGS=" -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fexceptions -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fnon-call-exceptions -pthread -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition "  CC="clang -target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu" CXX="clang++ -target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu"
```

I had patched only two files while building wxWidgets 3.1.0 vesrion to avoid errors: `include/wx/msw/private.h` and `src/msw/mediactrl_am.cpp`
In `src/msw/mediactrl_am.cpp` I had changed the constant in `case`:

```
case -609: // readystatechange in IActiveMovie2 and IMediaPlayer
```

and in `include/wx/msw/private.h` I changed lines with errors:

```
// close the handle in the class dtor
//template <wxUIntPtr INVALID_VALUE = (wxUIntPtr)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE>
template <wxUIntPtr INVALID_VALUE = (wxUIntPtr)-1>
class AutoHANDLE
```

and:

```
static HANDLE InvalidHandle()
{
    //return static_cast<HANDLE>(INVALID_VALUE);
    return reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(INVALID_VALUE);
}
```

It is very difficult to me to install tools like **MSYS2** on my job, so I would like to avoid using `configure`.

**Is there a way to repair wxWidgets dlls building with clang in my case?**

Comment: There are so many things here that I'm not sure what is the actual problem. Is it just the undefined reference to `wxAppConsoleBase::FilterEvent()`? If so, I'd start by running `nm` or `objdump` to see whether the symbol is actually defined in `coredll_appbase.o`, as it should be.

Comment: @VZ There is a problem, that I can't build any wxWidgets dlls (static libraries work fine, in monolithic dynamic build I can't build opengl dll). There are some errors for clang in wxWidgets headers. I tryed to add -DNOPCH, but this doesn't help